# Wine sound no longer works

Tags: wine

Wine, the program that allows for using Windows .exe files, no longer plays sound. How do I get the sound back on?

Answer (score 0):

In the search, type "configure wine" and run the application.
Open the Audio tab and set all the drop down lists to System Default.
Once changed, test the settings.

- If this doesnt work, try going through the list of all you audio devices and select which ever ones work.

Comment: I tried that a while ago ('System Default' is the only option for all four audio). No change. I also can't get the disk mount function to work. 'Failed to connect to the mount manager, the drive configuration can not be edited.'